# How to work with linear layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Hello I'm trying to figure how to work with LinearLayouts. I dragged one horizontal layout to my XML file, I then dragged three TextView one next to each other. When I'm trying to drag ImageView and place it below them, it always pushes the TextView aside. How can I fix this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="397dp"></LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Movie Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Actor Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Grade"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you want to place the ImageView under the TextView  (or) TextView of Linearlayout?

Comment: Why do you have **3 levels of nesting**? Each level lowers the overall performances. The `weightSum` is optional and in this case also **useless**. You should **close** all the LinearLayout tags. If you want the imageView to stay **below** the other Views, declare it **last**, since the layout is read **top-down**.

Comment: Explain How You want your UI ll look like ?

Comment: And **left to right**, unless you don't specify an RTL direction (useful for languages which write "in reverse").

Comment: thank you very much it was really helpful after i set the orientation of the main parent i was able to drag another layout below the 1st one and place their the image view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have not mentioned `orientation` for the main parent `LinearLayout` so by default it is considering it to be horizontal and showing images and text views in same line.
2. The following `LinearLayout` is useless as it does not have any children.
3. You need to declare orientation of `LinearLayout` to be `vertical` to show image below your other layout.

Some pseudo code will be like,

```
<LinearLayout
    orientation="vertical"
    ...>
          <LinearLayout
                  orientation="horizontal"
                  ...>
                      <TextViews ... />
           </LinearLayout>
           <ImageView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you very much it was really helpful after i set the orientation of the main parent i was able to drag another layout below the 1st one and place their the image view

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` is a view group that aligns all children in a single direction, vertically or horizontally. You can specify the layout direction with the `android:orientation` attribute.

All children of a `LinearLayout` are stacked one after the other, so a vertical list will only have one child per row, no matter how wide they are, and a horizontal list will only be one row high (the height of the tallest child, plus padding). A `LinearLayout` respects margins between children and the gravity (right, center, or left alignment) of each child.

So My suggestion is Dont use specific width and Height, ALways use `wrap_content` or `match_parent`

For More Details [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Comment: thank you very much it was really helpful after i set the orientation of the main parent i was able to drag another layout below the 1st one and place their the image view

Answer (score 0):

This is XML Code that You wants.

try the Below code. You should give the `android:orientation="vertical"`for the parent LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Movie Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Actor Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Grade"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Happy Coding :)